# How to fail or continue to next RSpec test after n seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

I want to fail (or continue to) an RSpec test if it takes longer than n seconds to complete. I am using this as a way to debug where the app is stalling during testing.

- **I need to wrap the test within a transaction.** I tried creating a `Timeout` block, but the database is not cleaned, and a thread is left open. Maybe database_cleaner could help here...
- Ideally, I want to replace the Capybara error (see below) with a custom message, like `'Forced Timeout'`

I am aware of putting `fail` in a test, but it only works if that line is read. Rather, if a test has been on the same line for, say, 10 seconds, I want it to move to the next test, either by failing or calling some `continue` method.

Example Capybara failure message:

```
1) Exercise Login page - log in as user type
   Failure/Error: fill_in "Username", with: @user.name
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     Unable to find field "Username"
```

Comment: You should implement the timeout not on the test but whatever is taking long.  So if you're long running process is trying to connect to something then your HTTP client (or whatever) should instrument it's own timeout.

Comment: @Anthony I agree with you, but at this point, I am unsure what is taking so long. For example, I ran my suite over lunch, but it stalled after 2 minutes, 10 tests. In this case, the last thing logged was `ROLLBACK` -- there's nothing to say how the Rollback crashed.

Comment: You want to use truncation instead of transactions when doing capybara specs - especially if you are using a javascript driver like webkit or selenium. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup

Comment: Also if you are using Webkit, Poltergeist or Selenium you can set the timeout on the driver level, see the documentation for each driver.

Comment: @max I did not know Poltergeist or Capybara Webkit had timeout methods. I will check the docs out, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an RSpec around hook in combination with with Ruby's Timeout.
Globally you can set it like this, but you can even do it on a specific test if you know which one is the problem.

```
require 'timeout'
time_limit = n

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.around(:each) do |example|
    Timeout::timeout(time_limit) {
      example.run
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using Capybara, and trying this out shows along the lines of "Cannot find element", instead of `Timeout` or something.

Comment: Update -- This does not work, as it affects database cleaning and threads. I will continue to look for a solution.